# How to send array from jquery to webmethod in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

I'd like to pass an array to a c# webmethod but don't have a good example to follow. Thanks for any assistance.

Here is what I have so far:

My array:

```
function ReadAllGridviewData() {

    var ArrayUph = new Array();

    GVUPHLineItems = document.getElementById("GVUPHLineItems");
    for (var i = 1; i < GVUPHLineItems.rows.length; i++) {
        var txtQty = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var txtStyle = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var spanstyleDesc = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('span');
        var txtPackage = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var txtPrice = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (txtStyle[0].value != '' && txtQty[0].value !='') {
            var ArryUph = new Array();
            ArryUph['LineNumber'] = i;
            ArryUph['Quantity'] = txtQty[0].value;
            ArryUph['Style'] = txtStyle[0].value;
            ArryUph['StyleDescription'] = spanstyleDesc[0].innerHTML;
            ArryUph['Package'] = txtPackage[0].value;
            ArryUph['SelectFlag'] = 'N';
            ArryUph['Price'] = 0.0;
            var ArryStyle = new Array();
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                var spanStyle = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[j].cells[0].innerText;
                var inputCoverId = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[j].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input');
                var inputColorID = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[j].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input');
                if (inputCoverId[0].value != '' && inputColorID[0].value != '') {
                    var tempArryStyle = new Array();
                    tempArryStyle['CoverPosition'] = spanStyle;
                    tempArryStyle['CoverID'] = inputCoverId[0].value;
                    tempArryStyle['ColorID'] = inputColorID[0].value;
                    ArryStyle.push(tempArryStyle);
                }
            }
            var ArryOptions = new Array();
            for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                var inputOpt = GVUPHLineItems.rows[i].cells[6].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[k].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
                if (inputOpt[0].value != '') {
                    var tempArryOptions = new Array();
                    tempArryOptions['Opt'] = inputOpt[0].value;
                    ArryOptions.push(tempArryOptions);
                }
            }
            ArryUph['StyleCovers'] = ArryStyle;
            ArryUph['Options'] = ArryOptions;
            ArrayUph.push(ArryUph);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Jquery call:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: "OrderEntry.aspx/ValidateUph",
         data: JSON.stringify({ ArrayUph: ArrayUph }),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
              var validstyle = data.d;
         }
 });
```

Comment: What's the result of the call ? What does the data look like in the aspx page (provided it's received) ? Can you provide an example of an array being sent, what it looks like server-side, and what you expect in return ?

Comment: Really, ArrayUph should not be an array in Javascript - it should be an object.  Although your code maybe works (because arrays are objects too), it is just creating confusion to call it an array.  (So really your question is "how to send an object from jquery to a webmethod").

Comment: if I were you, I will JSON the array to a string and send to server